# JQuery 'Unexpected token o' while $.parseJSON()

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

My controller returns

```
return Json(new PersonViewModel { Message = "Description exists" });
```

here is the associated class

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

At client side i try to parse the json returned by the controller.

```
.success(function (Message) {
                            var returnedData = $.parseJSON(Message);
```

which renders as [image]

and returns the `Unexpected token o` error.

So, what is the issue? How can i fix this?

**UPDATE**

If i do not try to parse the response i get the `[object Object]` thing...

Thank you

Comment: it is already json, why are you parsing it ?

Comment: like @EhsanSajjad said, you can straight away use it. you don't need to parse it again.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Can you please check the update?

Comment: what are you expecting from it? if you are putting alert you will see **object object**, if you want to see what is returned from server use ``Console.log(Message)`` or ``alert(JSON.stringify(Message))``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad That is true but i do not know, how to extract the message description it contains

Comment: you need to do `console.log(Message.Message)`

Comment: can you show what is the json returned by doing the way i showed in last comment

Comment: @Sushil Great! Do you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: posted my solution @Chocol8. please upvote and accept it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Chocol8 can you please mark my answer as a solution and upvote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a valid `JSON` and you don't need to `parse` it again.

Try this:

```
.success(function (Message) {
    var returnedData = Message;
    console.log(returnedData.Message); // this will give you the output as "Description Exists"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json is already parsed. It is an object as shown by the debugger,you don't need to parse it again, all you have to do is to access its property as below:

```
.success(function (response) {
  var returnedData = response.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. Try copy/pasting the JSON into http://jsonlint.com/